# How to slideTo() only if the loadmore button is clicked using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my script I load some posts from external RSS feeds. I have a "load more" button that when it is clicked, calls the `loadfeed()` function and shows some 10 more posts.

When this happens, there is a `slideTo()` that slides the browser to the first of the new posts list.

In addition to the "load more" button, I have a timer that checks for any new posts of those feeds. This happens every 3 minutes.

As I said, if you click on the "load more" button, the page is moved with the first new post on the top of your screen. The problem here is that this sliding happens also if you clicked once the "load more" button, you read the articles, and as you read the 3 minutes are passed, you slide back to the first post of the new list you loaded. More specific, when you load (from the default 20) +10 more posts, you will be slided to the 21st post after 3 minutes.

So my question here it is how to avoid this?

this is the #loadmore button that calls loadfeed()

```
$("#loadmore").click(function() {
    cap += 10;
    loadfeed();

});
```

and this is a part of loadfeed() that handles sliding. I have an if statement for the sliding to happen after the default 20 posts. Without this you will be slide to the 11 post after 3 minutes and no "load more" is clicked.

```
if (cap > 20) {
$(".p" + (cap-9)).slideto({
    slide_duration : 'slow'
});
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forgive me if I've misunderstood, but can't you just pass a parameter to `loadfeed()`?

In `$("#loadmore").click`, call `loadfeed(true)` and for the timer call `setTimeout(function () { loadfeed(false); }, 12000);`. Or similar.

**Edit**:

I don't know which slideto plugin you're using. I've downloaded 2 of them, but neither works as yours seems to. I have got this to work with the [scrollTo plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo).

In this code, I've removed all of the AJAX bits and some other things that didn't seem relevant to the question. The basic changes are to add a parameter to `loadfeed()` that tells it whether or not to scroll when adding new content. Clicking the button makes it scroll to the bottom; waiting for the timer does not. (I've also added a clearTimeout to stop the timer triggering multiple times if someone goes crazy with the load button.)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Testing</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .Top { background-color: #ccc; padding: 10px; position: fixed; }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.scrollTo.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function ()
        {
            var cap = 0;
            var timerId = null;

            function loadfeed(scroll)
            {
                cap++;
                $("#loadmore").hide();
                $('#feed')
                .addClass('loading')
                .append("<div class=\"p" + cap + "\"><p>Biodiesel put a bird on it pitchfork beard cosby sweater tattooed, 3 wolf moon skateboard thundercats. Craft beer irony sartorial DIY. Portland photo booth trust fund, mlkshk yr you probably haven't heard of them salvia. Trust fund marfa food truck Austin etsy synth. Seitan chambray williamsburg, thundercats american apparel cardigan four loko letterpress food truck cosby sweater. Art party Austin biodiesel, single-origin coffee etsy organic mlkshk yr PBR. Skateboard master cleanse 3 wolf moon, freegan Austin tumblr messenger bag vinyl dreamcatcher.</p><p>Tumblr before they sold out helvetica, chambray iphone yr DIY cosby sweater PBR synth stumptown keytar. Letterpress you probably haven't heard of them iphone, keffiyeh photo booth chambray american apparel lomo artisan. Hoodie beard quinoa locavore four loko mixtape. Tofu stumptown viral you probably haven't heard of them, readymade thundercats echo park etsy 8-bit. Pitchfork ethical before they sold out, freegan keffiyeh yr marfa banh mi echo park williamsburg tofu PBR twee. Keffiyeh pitchfork food truck, gluten-free bicycle rights iphone fixie banh mi vinyl craft beer tofu keytar +1 brooklyn. Synth echo park letterpress locavore, chambray butcher banh mi vinyl tofu twee four loko food truck beard mustache fap.</p></div>")
                .removeClass('loading');
                if (timerId !== null) clearTimeout(timerId);
                timerId = setTimeout(function () { loadfeed(false); }, 12000);
                $("#loadmore").show();

                if (scroll) $(window).scrollTo(".p" + cap);
            }

            loadfeed();

            $("#loadmore").click(function ()
            {
                loadfeed(true);
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="Top"><button id="loadmore">Load</button></div>
    <div id="feed">Feed</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It didn't work. It keeps sliding to the post after the time is passed.

Comment: so you are punishing the person who takes time to read through your question and gives a reply based on what he understood! instead of down voting suggest a way to clear your question

Comment: @JamesSmith I removed the downvote to avoid the conversation.

Comment: I'm sorry that didn't work for you. As @JamesSmith said, I obviously didn't understand your problem. I'm still not sure I do. Unfortunately I wasn't able to respond more quickly as I haven't used the slideto plugin and I'm not sure how it works. I've downloaded 2 of them, but neither seems to work as yours appears to. I have now updated the answer with a working solution (to the problem as I understand it at least). I'm afraid that, for me at least, finding a plugin that I can use and coding a working solution can take a little time.

Comment: Thank you for this, I accepted your answer. I will keep it as a reference in case that I find any bugs in mine. I have user an If statement that checks if hasClass. I add a class when the #loadmore is clicked.